# Laravel 'Route Not Defined' when route is clearly defined

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I'm remaking the registration for my site, and have made a form that takes e-mail, password etc:

```
<form method="POST" class="etc" action="{{ route('register/blade/create') }}">
...
</form>
```

Then of course, my submit button in the form submits it and from routes in **web.php**:

```
Route::post('/register/basic/create', 'RegisterController@create');
```

However, every time I load this page, I get the following error:

[image]

I tried following others who had similar problems that posted on stack overflow, creating a named route, but that didn't seem to do the trick either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use named route `route` then you have to specify routes name in your `routes/web.php` file. Like this

routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/register/basic/create', 'RegisterController@create')->name('register');
```

In blade file

```
<form method="POST" class="etc" action="{{ route('register') }}">
...
</form>
```

Check details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes

Comment: That did it. You're the best. Thanks so much! Will mark as answered in 10min. :)

Comment: @CodeToLife if it worked for you then please upvote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the above error occurs when you have two routes with the same **uri** but different **callbacks** and different **route name**

For example

```
Route::post('update','PermissionController@update')->name('update_permission');`

Route::post('update','RoleController@update')->name('update_role');
```

The above routes update different resources but it will still return an error Route `update_permission` not defined or Route `update_role` not defined.

So the best thing to do is to use a different uri in each route so as to prevent conflict like this

```
Route::post('/role_permission/update','RoleController@update')->name('update_role');`

Route::post('/permission/update','PermissionController@update')->name('update_permission');
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use this command

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: This solved my issue! What does this do differently than clearing the route cache?

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility that you cashed the route so clear route cashe

> php artisan route:clear

if you still not finding your route After clearing cache, then remove the route and re-write your route with different keywords, hope you will find the problem

Comment: Good idea, but in my case where routes are well defined, it didn't solve my problem. **EDIT :** In my case, I am re making an old site entirely and I had the same route (the new one with "name", the old one without) and it created a conflict. By removing the old route, the route with "name" finally worked

Comment: When I started Laravel, this issue (same URL with different name) took 2 days, in your case you had tow routes with the same URL. no matter if they have different names or only one of them has a different name. URL should be unique otherwise there will be conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 10, it uses class variable scope

```
Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
```